# ContentControl With ScrollViewer, Focus

Tags: c#, windows-8, focus, windows-runtime, contentcontrol

In my Windows 8 Metro project, I'm using a class derived from ContentControl (let's call it MyControl) to present my content. Inside MyControl I have a ScrollViewer. Because I want my control to handle keyboard events, I need to be able to set the focus to my control. However, I also want the option to let the scrollviewer handle keyevents, such as arrow keys and PageUp/Down. More precisely, I want this to be an option that another programmer can turn on or off. This means that sometimes, I want MyControl to be a tab-stop, and sometimes I want ScrollViewer to be a tab-stop, but never both.

The issue is that I don't want to expose the inner workings of MyControl to other programmers. That is, they ideally should be able to use MyControl.IsTabStop and leave the logic of placing the actual tab-stop with my Control (to put in MyControl or ScrollViewer).

Is there any good way to achieve this, or do I somehow have to work around it by providing a separate function to make my control a tab stop?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at my test XAML you'll see I'm doing nothing, yet the up/down keys in the TextBox work to go between lines of text and they scroll the ScrollViewer when there is no line of text to go to. This is likely achieved by the KeyDown handlers setting the e.Handled value to true when they don't want the key event to bubble up (as when the TextBox already handled it) and leaving it false when the event is not handled, which lets the ScrollViewer handle it. The event will always trigger on the TextBox if it has focus, but it bubbles up the visual tree if it is not handled. It does not seem that you have to do anything more than just deciding whether you want to mark the key events as handled or not.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer
        IsTabStop="True">
        <Grid
            Width="2000"
            Height="2000">
            <Button
                Margin="149,342,0,311">
                <Button>
                    <TextBox
                        AcceptsReturn="True"
                        Height="400"
                        Width="200"/></Button>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I guess my question isn't clear enough.
IF you hit the tab key you will alternate focus between the TextBox and ScrollViewer.

Imagine you stuck a ScrollViewer inside a FlipView and set both their IsTabStop to true. If you now click on ScrollViewer, it will have focus as opposed to the FlipView. However, if you hit tab, both the flipview and the scrollviewer can be focused on.

Now, let's assume you have your own control that has this structure inside it. Let's say you provide the user of this control with an option to turn the scrollviewer's key handling off. How do you keep this transparent?

Comment: Not sure what you mean still. Do you want to provide an option to do TabStop on the ScrollViewer in the control template? Just do a {TemplateBinding} on the ScrollViewer's TabStop property to bind it to a DependencyProperty that you define on your control. This is not very likely to be clear to the user of this control though. I'd say the ScrollViewer should never have TabStop set to true, but if someone wants it that way - they can edit your control's template and make it so.

Comment: Hmm, if the ScrollViewer doesn't have IsTabStop=true, how will it receive keyboard input? As far as I know, in order to get keyboard input, either you or a child of yours needs to be in focus. If my control is in focus, and the ScrollViewer is a child of my control, then keyboard input will not go through the ScrollViewer.

I hope I'm not misunderstanding something about this whole thing...

Comment: That's what my answer was all about - it does not need to have focus to receive keyboard input as long as any control inside of it has focus.

Comment: I see where we've misunderstood each other.

I don't want to give the control focus. I want the control that is inside to have the focus (i.e. the ScrollViewer).

Comment: Well, if you put something in there that can't get focus, but you still want your ScrollViewer to be usable with keyboard - you can check if the content's visual tree has IsTabStop set to true somewhere and set the ScrollViewer's IsTabStop to true if it doesn't, but it still makes more sense for the user of the control to make it focusable, so for example if they only show an image inside of it and they want scrollviewer to work - they would set IsTabStop on the image to true. Adding yet another property would be unnecessary and potentially confusing.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about confusing the user with the extra options.

In this case though, the user isn't in control of the scrollviewer. Ideally, I want the whole thing to be transparent. That is, my control displays some content and the user simply gets the benefit of automatic scrolling on key presses if the control is a tab stop, and no automatic scrolling if it isn't. That way, the user can choose if they want to create their own scrolling behavior or not.

Comment: Well then, just bind the ScrollViewer's IsTabStop property to the one of your control.

Comment: Which leaves me with just 1 issue left. Tab navigation will get somewhat awkward... now hitting tab can get you to both of them, so sometimes you get the scrolling behavior, and sometimes not.

Oh, and by the way. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: Well, then you can add another awkward property and use that instead of the IsTabStop one - like IsTabStopScrollViewer on the control itself to control it.